# Strike orginal price and show advanced pricing and show total saving in 2.3.3

Tags: configurable-product, price, mini-cart, dropdown-attribute, advanced-pricing

I have a configurable product in which each simple product is given as advanced pricing.
I need to show the both **advanced** **pricing** and the **original** **price** to be **striked** out as shown below.

It has to get applied on the **cart** and **mini** **cart** section also.

[image: The configurable product selection dropdown]

[image: The mini cart section example.]

I need to display the total saving also in mini cart and checkout.

i.e **Original price -Advanced price = Total saving** for each product

Can anyone tell how to acheieve this?

Thanks in advance.